# Understanding the polytabloid associated with a Young tabeau

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Suppose I have the Young tableau $T$:

$[1][2][3][4]$

$[5][6]$

With corresponding *tabloid* $\{T\}$ (the equivalence class of Young tableaux).

We define the notion of the *column stabilizer* for a Young tableau (denoted $C(T)$) and we define the *polytabloid* associated to the Young tableau $T$ as follows:

[image: what is this object??]

I'm struggling to understand what the *polytabloid* is.  Is it a vector?  Or at least expressible or representable as a column vector?

Thank you for your insights.

All of this can be found on the following paper by Redmond McNamara:

[Irreducible Representations of the Symmetric group by Redmond McNamara](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2013/REUPapers/McNamara.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

This polytabloid lies in the free Abelian group generated by the tabloids.
(Does your book have a notation for this group?)
(In your example, with tableaux of shape $4\,2$ that would be a free
Abelian group of rank $15$.)
That's the additive group with one generator for each tabloid $\{T\}$.
Then as the formula suggests, starting with the tableau $T$, one applies
all possible permutations $\pi$ fixing the columns in $T$, resulting in tableaux $\pi\ast T$. Then take the associated tabloids $\{\pi\ast T\}$,
weight them according to the sign of $\pi$ and add them all up in this
free Abelian group. That sum is what you have pointed out in your diagram.

(I've used slightly different notation: $\{\pi\ast T\}$ rather than $\pi\ast\{T\}$.)